Correctly modelling a continuous log dose-response relationship in meta-regression for small dosages
I’m looking at the effectiveness of a type of programme that can have a range of number of sessions, 1 to 20. I start with a meta-analysis (k = 70) that tells me the average effect size for that type of programme is 0.50 SDs. In my meta-analysis, the average number of sessions is 7. I want to predict the effect of an implementation of that programme with 1 session.
(1) I could start by predicting it as 0.50 * (1/7) = 0.07. Where 1/7 = 0.14 serves as a linear adjustment for the number of sessions (i.e., the dosage). However, I think a concave dose-response relationship is more plausible than a linear one. So maybe I should do ln(1)/ln(7) instead. Well, that doesn’t work because ln(1) = 0. So I could do ln(1+1)/ln(7+1) = 0.33?
However, I haven’t seen precedent for this. I don’t think people do models with ln(income+1) for example – income being the main variable I’ve seen treated this way – although that might be unimportant because income is in 1000s rather than 1 to 20. It is also unclear whether a constant other than +1 would be appropriate.
(2) Instead of using a general adjustment for dosage, maybe I want to anchor it with more evidence. I could predict the dose-response relationship with a meta-regression where I predict the effect with the number of sessions attended. If I want a log dose-response relationship, do I use ln(sessions) as my predictor or do I use ln(sessions+1)? Would that change the meaning of the intercept, where the intercept for ln(sessions) is the effect for when sessions = 1 because ln(1) = 0 but the intercept for ln(sessions+1) is for when sessions = 0 because ln(0+1) = 0?
(3) If my model gives me an intercept of 0.20 SDs and an effect of 0.65 SDs per session, could I then calculate the adjustment as (0.20 + ln(1+1)*0.65)/(0.20 + ln(7+1)*0.65) = 0.42?
(4) Does mean-centring this predictor change anything in terms of interpretation and calculating the adjustment?
Thank you for your time!

I would not do (1) as this makes very strong assumptions. Instead, meta-regression seems much more sensible to me. If you want to use the log-transformed number of sessions as the predictor, then I don't see any need to add some (arbitrary) constant to the number of sessions before the log transformation (I assume 1 is the minimum number of sessions). So just fit the model with ln(sessions) as predictor. The intercept of that model is the estimated effect size when sessions=1 (since ln(1) = 0). No need for what you are doing under (3). Therefore, there is also no need to center the predictor, since you are in fact interested in the case where ln(sessions) is equal to 0.
You could also consider modeling the non-linear association using spline - see here for some examples.

And if there are zero session people I would use a dummy variable to identify them as they may be a special case.
